# Natbib not printing arXiv eprint no

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, arxiv

I ran into a problem related to Natbib. My .bib file looks like this

```
@article{Flacke:2016szy,
    author         = "Flacke, Thomas and Frugiuele, Claudia and Fuchs, Elina
    and Gupta, Rick S. and Perez, Gilad",
    title          = "{Phenomenology of relaxion-Higgs mixing}",
    journal        = "JHEP",
    volume         = "06",
    year           = "2017",
    pages          = "050",
    doi            = "10.1007/JHEP06(2017)050",
    eprint         = "1610.02025",
    archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
    primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
    reportNumber   = "CTPU-16-25",
    SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1610.02025;%%" 
}
```

But in the printed bibliography this is coming like

```
[1] Thomas Flacke, Claudia Frugiuele, Elina Fuchs, Rick S. Gupta, and Gilad
Perez. Phenomenology of relaxion-Higgs mixing. JHEP, 06:050, 2017.1.
```

without the  arxiv eprint no.

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and also tried other style files as well. It would be very helpful to me if someone can shade some light about how to solve this issue. I forgot to mention I am using `\documentclass{scrbook}` that's why `\bibliographystyle{hunsrt}` is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried bibliographystyle{hunsrt}  but this is not working with scrbook document class.

Comment: Please add some compilable code, we need a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use the `note` field:

```
@article{Flacke:2016szy,
    author         = "Flacke, Thomas and Frugiuele, Claudia and Fuchs, Elina
    and Gupta, Rick S. and Perez, Gilad",
    title          = "{Phenomenology of relaxion-Higgs mixing}",
    journal        = "JHEP",
    volume         = "06",
    year           = "2017",
    pages          = "050",
    doi            = "10.1007/JHEP06(2017)050",
    note         = "arXiv: 1610.02025",
    archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
    primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
    reportNumber   = "CTPU-16-25",
    SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1610.02025;%%" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `natbib` with the style provided by [arXive.org](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/), in this case `hunsrtnat.bst`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Flacke:2016szy,
    author         = "Flacke, Thomas and Frugiuele, Claudia and Fuchs, Elina
    and Gupta, Rick S. and Perez, Gilad",
    title          = "{Phenomenology of relaxion-Higgs mixing}",
    journal        = "JHEP",
    volume         = "06",
    year           = "2017",
    pages          = "050",
    doi            = "10.1007/JHEP06(2017)050",
    eprint         = "1610.02025",
    archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
    primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
    reportNumber   = "CTPU-16-25",
    SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1610.02025;%%"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{hunsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I'm getting an error saying that `\bibliographystyle{hunsrtnat}` not found.

Comment: You have to get it from arXive.org, as mentioned above: https://arxiv.org/hypertex/bibstyles/